# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java application where I am getting the below error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com/crossview/commerce/dataload/reader/OfferReader.getNode()Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;
    at com.wkus.taa.commerce.dataload.reader.OfferReader.init(OfferReader.java:57)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.AbstractBusinessObjectLoader.initializeDataReaders(AbstractBusinessObjectLoader.java:1220)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.AbstractBusinessObjectLoader.init(AbstractBusinessObjectLoader.java:353)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.BusinessObjectLoader.init(BusinessObjectLoader.java:65)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.DataLoaderMain.execute(DataLoaderMain.java:428)
    at com.ibm.commerce.foundation.dataload.DataLoaderMain.main(DataLoaderMain.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:260)
```

But the method `getNode()` is present in the code. 
Any clues why I am seeing this error?

I have a child class OfferReader.java which is calling the getNode() from super class.

```
public void init() throws DataLoadException {
        super.init();
        node = super.getNode();
    }
```

And parent class OfferReaderParent.java has the below method signature:

```
public Node getNode() {
        return node;
    }

    public void setNode(Node node) {
        this.node = node;
    }
```

Comment: taking that argument? and is it the only version of that class in the CLASSPATH?

Comment: Please suggest how to check the differences of file versions from CLASSPATH.

Comment: Can you please post the signature of that method, and the way you are calling it too?

Comment: I have edited the question. Posted the signature of method.

Answer (score 0):

Although this post is quite old, I am answering this question as someone might be having same problem as above and matches a scenario which I was struggling with.

I was facing a similar issue, which on closer inspection was found to have two same classes within two same package names although under different modules. For example, Say you have two projects a JAVA Client and Web Client deployed to your server packaged in same EAR file.

> **JavaClient >> test.java.somepackage.SomeClass**
>
> **WebClient >> test.java.somepackage.SomeClass**
>
> both packaged within **TestProjectEAR.ear**

In such case if you have deployed your project on your server, server might try to look for methods in the wrong class which are having the same name, thus causing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError.

I hope this might help some people who may come here looking for answers. :)